# C#, Access database DESC

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-order-by

I'm trying to retrieve records in DESC order.

I can retrieve them in order with:

```
"SELECT * FROM BillPayAccount ORDER BY LEN(DueDate), DueDate";
```

This makes sure that "10" doesn't appear before "2". When I try the same thing with DESC order, I end up with "8, 9, 30, 29, 28, 27, etc..

Basically all of the double digit numbers are correct but it places the single digit numbers at the beginning.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM BillPayAccount ORDER BY LEN(DueDate), DueDate";
```

Comment: Sounds like alphabetical sorting, is it a string instead of number?

Comment: What data type is the `DueDate` column? It appears that it's not a date/time field of some sort and if you control the database you should definitely change that ASAP.

Comment: I do have that column configured for "short text".

Comment: omg, so no wonder it doesnt work. It isnt a number.

Comment: You're sorting by the length of the date ascending and the date itself descending I bet.  Put DESC on both I guess.  Though I need a shower after suggesting this.

Comment: I believe if I change the format of that column, it should behave as needed.

Comment: It really, really should.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a number:

```
"SELECT * FROM BillPayAccount ORDER BY Val(DueDate) Desc"
```

However, if *DueDate* is a date, do change the data type of the field to DateTime or you will forever encounter troubles.